# Creation of heat map(spectrogram) using Winrt xaml toolkit multiple line series

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, heatmap, spectrogram

I am creating heat maps in Windows store apps 8.1 using algorithm provided in stack overflow.

first approach:

```
public Color HeatMapColor(decimal value, decimal min, decimal max)
{
    decimal val = (value - min) / (max - min);
    int r = Convert.ToByte(255 * val);
    int g = Convert.ToByte(255 * (1 - val));
    int b = 0;

    return Color.FromArgb(255,r,g,b);                                    
}
```

second approach:

```
    public Brush getColourTemp(int maxVal,int minVal ,double actual )
    {
        int maxVal = 70000000;
        int minVal = 100000;

        var midVal = (maxVal - minVal) / 2;
        int intR;
        int intG;
        int intB = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(0.0));

        if (actual >= midVal)
        {
            intR = 255;
            intG = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(255 * ((maxVal - actual) / (maxVal - midVal))));
        }
        else
        {
            intG = 255;
            intR = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(255 * ((actual) - minVal) / (midVal - minVal)));
        }
        //  Color background = Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)ran.Next(255), (byte)ran.Next(255), (byte)ran.Next(255));
        Color background = Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)intR, (byte)intG, (byte)intB);

        return new SolidColorBrush(background);

         //byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(actual);
         //return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]));


      //  return to_rgb(intR, intG, intB);
    }
```

But in both the case blue colour is zero why. I need blue color in heat map also can any one help me out.

I am creating heat map using Winrt xaml toolkit line graphs

**code details**

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
        {`enter code here`
            if (i > 25)
            {

                LineChart.Series.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            List<FinancialStuff> financialStuffList = new List<FinancialStuff>();
            LineSeries line = new LineSeries();
            line.Title = "";

            line.IndependentValuePath = "Name";
            line.DependentValuePath = "Amount";
            for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++)
            {
                financialStuffList.Add(new FinancialStuff() { Name = i, Amount = j - 130, FavoriteColor = ConvertTotalToRgb(i, j) });




            }
            line.ItemsSource = financialStuffList;

            line.DataPointStyle = style;
            LineChart.Series.Add(line);

            if (i >= 25)
            { 
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            }
```

//******************************************************************************

```
   public Brush ConvertTotalToRgb(int val, int val1)
    {`enter code here`
        double actual = 0.0;
        int range = 70000000 - 100000;
        actual = data[val, val1];
        int main = Convert.ToInt32(255 * actual / range);
        string hexR = main.ToString("X2");
        int flip = Convert.ToInt32(255 * (1 - (actual / range)));
        string hexB = flip.ToString("X2");
        string colorValue = "#" + hexR + "00" + hexB;
        byte R = Convert.ToByte(colorValue.Substring(1, 2), 16);
        byte G = Convert.ToByte(colorValue.Substring(3, 2), 16);
        byte B = Convert.ToByte(colorValue.Substring(5, 2), 16);
        Color background = Color.FromArgb((byte)255, R, G, B);
        return new SolidColorBrush(background);
    }




        }
```

very bad performance after i=50 it is very slow and not loading may be performance issue of in line graphs as it is huge number.
Please help if any body can tell improvement or suggests other ways to create Spectrogram in windows store apps 8.1 development.

XAML page

```
<Page   xmlns:Charting="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting" 
x:Class="MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Spect"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid >
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style
            x:Key="ColorByPreferenceColumn"
           x:Name="abc"
            TargetType="Charting:LineDataPoint">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />

            <Setter Property="Template"  >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate
                        TargetType="Charting:LineDataPoint">


                        <Grid Background="{Binding FavoriteColor}">

                            <Polygon>
                                <Polygon.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#77ffffff" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00ffffff" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Polygon.Fill>

                            </Polygon>
                           </Grid>


                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

        </Style>

    </Grid.Resources>
    <Charting:Chart x:Name="LineChart"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="300" Height="600" Margin="208,107,0,0">

    </Charting:Chart>
    <Button Content="Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="175,31,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: `int intB = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(0.0));` I wouldn't trust an algorithm from somebody who writes this kind of statement

Comment: Can anybody suggest better approach to get heat map colors?

Comment: There's been a lot of work around this type of thing documented out there in the wild for some inspiration. Examples, [link](http://www.andrewnoske.com/wiki/Code_-_heatmaps_and_color_gradients), [link](https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/how-to-create-heat-maps-in-native-windows-store-apps-2/), [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821828/calculating-heat-map-colours)

Comment: I tried all option blue color is coming in one of the option but yellow is not coming.In other option yellow is coming but blue is not coming

Comment: Can anybody help me to how to hide the title(title and box) of line series in winrt xaml toolkit?                                                                         LineSeries line = new LineSeries();
                line.Title = ""; but this will hide only name not the box as I have array of data which I am putting in more than 200 line series.Please help me to hide the box and improve the performance of Chart having more than 200 line graphs.

Comment: I think there used to be a question around here about hiding the legend somewhere. I'd look it up. Overall - the chart control won't ever work with large amounts of data and does not support heat maps. I would try dumping the bits directly into a `WriteableBitmap` or use DX if WB is too slow.

Comment: Thanks for Reply Filip                                                                                                       As I have created heat map(spectrogram) by using above code but due to huge amount of data it is very slow.